# What produces this NMR spectrum?

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I'm having difficulty deciphering this 13C and 1H-NMR spectra. I've tried figuring it out, and have gotten close and am pretty sure it contains a methoxy group attached to a benzyl group, but hit a rut in regard to the other structure. Any help would be super appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What would really help is a mass ion. Is this a spectrum from a compound you can reanalyse? If so, run a DEPT so you can pinpoint the inverted peaks as CH2. Possibly also run COSY /HMQC correlation experiments.

Comment: @Beerhunter the formula is on the top in red and everything looks really nicely formatted, so I think this might be a homework problem of some sort

Comment: @szentsas nice spot. Thanks. I was being dopey

Comment: @Beerhunter, yes the formula is in the top right. It's a practice problem for an exam. It's difficult for me to do these problems when the formula gets big. I could do others, but not this one.

Comment: Did they provide any more information?

Comment: @szentsas, no they did not, just the 1H and 13C NMR data and the actual chemical formula, as you noted in the top left. I tried simulating potential chemical structures to see if I could get the right 1H and 13C outputs, but I couldn't get it to coalesce

Comment: One more hint I was given... apparently this molecule is a product of a reaction that includes 1,3,5-pentanetriol. Maybe 1,3,5-pentanetriol that has hydroxy's methylated and connected to a benzene with a methoxy group?

Comment: Also the benzene ring has to be para-substituted because of the equivalence of the carbons and the positions and also their coupling pattern

Comment: @szentas, definitely. That's what explains the 1H peaks around 7, and the double C peaks